# How to check (debug) if JPA query get result from cache or from database

Tags: java, jpa, caching, eclipselink

I have simple JPA query

```
  Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery("SELECT pn FROM ProductsNames pn"
            + " WHERE pn.languages = :language"
            + " ORDER BY pn.products.id ASC");
    query.setParameter("language", language);
  return query.getResultList();
```

How can I check if result of these method return the list of objects from cache or direct from database?

in persistence.xml I have set the following paramter:

```
 <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="FINE"/>
```

so on output of server I can monitor executed queries (but Im not sure of that  - if query are visible on output that`s mean the query was sent to database or that mean the query was sent to entityManager and entityManager decide to use cache and later sent query to database).

So how I can distinguish which result of object are from:

- direct from database
- direct from cache

I Will grateful for help.

Comment: Your configuration says EclipseLink but your tag says Hibernate. This will be provider-specific.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can enable the [Performance Monitoring](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Advanced_JPA_Development/Performance/Performance_Monitoring_and_Profiling/Performance_Monitoring):

```
<property name="eclipselink.profiler" value="PerformanceMonitor"/>
```

So, you can execute your query many times you want and access [some cache statistics](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Monitoring), like the number of times that your query hit the cache:

```
Integer cacheHits = (Integer)((PerformanceMonitor)session.getProfiler())
    .getOperationTimings()
    .get(SessionProfiler.CacheHits);
```

If you want collect more details in more complex scenarios, the PerformanceMonitor already do this for you:

> The performance monitor will output a dump of cumulative statistics
>   every minute to the EclipseLink log.
>
> The statics contains three sets of information:
>
> - Info: Statistics that are constant informational data, such as the
>     session name, or time of login.
> - Counter: Statistics that are cumulative counters of total operations, such as cache hits, or query executions.
> - Timer: Statistics that are cumulative measurements of total time (in nano seconds) for a specific type of operation, reading, writing, database operations. Statistics are generally grouped in total and also by query type, query class, and query name.
>
> Counters and timers are generally recorded for the same operations, so
>   the time per operation could also be calculated.

Comment: Can you elaborate which session in the given snippet session.getProfiler() and where to import or declare it

Comment: @Reenu, It's the Hibernate (JPA) session. If you are using entity manager, you can get the session using `entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);`.

Comment: I am trying to do this in #openliberty, but get Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.persistence.tools.profiler.PerformanceMonitor.

Any idea whats missing? I actually print out my reference and it is of type PerformanceMonitor, but casting it generates the exception.